# How to add multiple dependencies to debian package?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, deb

Below is the working control file while creating debian package using the [link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=910717).
I kept a single dependency and it is creating the deb file.

```
Package: my-program
Version: 1.0
Architecture: all
Essential: no
Priority: optional
Depends: default-jdk
Maintainer: Your Name
Description: A short desc
```

But if I keep multiple dependencies, I am getting error.
The dependencies I kept are not actual, just for testing.

```
Package: my-program
Version: 1.0
Architecture: all
Essential: no
Priority: optional
Depends: default-jdk;net-tools
Maintainer: Your Name
Description: A short desc
```

> dpkg-deb --build my-program_version_architecture/ dpkg-deb: error:
> parsing file 'my-program_version_architecture//DEBIAN/control' near
> line 6 package 'my-program':  'Depends' field, invalid package name
> 'default-jdk;net-tools': character ';' not allowed (only letters,
> digits and characters '-+._')

Even for the deb file created with single dependency, when I am trying to install, I am getting error as below, for the folder I kept in DEBIAN folder for installation.

> dpkg: error processing archive
> /home/azureuser/my-program_version_architecture.deb (--unpack):
> unable to open file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci//testing': Is a directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntactically, the `;` is not the correct separator, but `,`. Therefore, it is treated as a part of the package name. From [Declaring relationships between packages](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#syntax-of-relationship-fields), emphasis is mine:

> These fields all have a uniform syntax. They are a list of package
> names **separated by commas**.
>
> In
> the `Depends`, `Recommends`, `Suggests`, `Pre-Depends`, `Build-Depends`, `Build-Depends-Indep` and `Build-Depends-Arch` control
> fields of the package, which declare dependencies on other packages,
> the package names listed may also include lists of alternative package
> names, separated by vertical bar (pipe) symbols `|`. In such a case,
> that part of the dependency can be satisfied by any one of the
> alternative packages.

They also give examples:

> ```
> Package: mutt 
> Version: 1.3.17-1 
> Depends: libc6 (>= 2.2.1), default-mta | mail-transport-agent
> ```

It is also good to take a look at the [Syntax of control files](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#syntax-of-control-files).

Comment: Thank you, I need to install tomcat  Version 9.0.35 and deploy some war files and install some related files. Can you suggest how to do this.

Comment: And also getting error while installing some files. dpkg: error processing archive /home/azureuser/my-program_version_architecture.deb (--unpack): unable to open file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci//testing': Is a directory

Comment: These are other, distinguished questions. Please open other questions on these issues, preferably one at a time and with a lot more details. In order to help solving a problem one should be able to replicate it.

Comment: I submitted one question for tomcat and war file. https://serverfault.com/questions/1055365/how-to-create-debian-file-to-install-tomcat-and-deploy-a-war-file.

Comment: And also this: https://serverfault.com/questions/1055375/how-to-create-a-deb-package-to-install-files